# Looping through array field in mysql statement?

Tags: mysql, arrays, loops

I was given a database that is a little weird, but I am not able to change it. There is a field that is set as an array but holds ids that I need to access in where clauses. Here is the field set up:

```
TABLE: PROMOS
promo_id   |    contract_ids
-----------------------------
 1               23,34,54
 2               13,34,55
 3               20,30
```

I need to do an sql query to get all promo_ids where contract id = 34

```
mysql_query("SELECT promo_id FROM Promos WHERE contract_ids = '34'
```

Is there a way to do this?? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT promo_id FROM Promos 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(34, contract_ids) > 0
```

See [FIND_IN_SET doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)